# Python advanced string searching with operators and boolean

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a function that searches a string in a list of lists then returns a list containing the matching lists:

```
def foo(myList,keyword,first=True):
    if first: #Search only first element or each sublist
        return [x for x in myList if keyword in x]
    else: #Search first and second elements of each sublist
        return [x for x in myList if keyword in x or keyword in x[1]]
```

Now I want to extend it to handle advanced searching with queries like:

```
matchthis -butnothis -"and not this"

this|orthis|"or this"

brand new*laptop  # this is a wildcard, matches like: brand new dell laptop

"exact phrase"
```

Are there any python modules (preferably builtin) that I can use in my function to handle these queries?

PS: I'm aware of Swoosh but it's not the right fit for me at the moment. Also, I'm currently using App Engine.

What I'm trying to do basically is full-text search in memory, since app engine doens't support full-text search yet. I query the datastore, put the entities into lists and loop through those lists to find query matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try constructing a regex for each portion of the search query.  First you could break the query into the portions using `shlex.split()`, and then create each regex individually.  Here is my crack at it:

```
import shlex, re

def foo(query):
    pieces = shlex.split(query)
    include, exclude = [], []
    for piece in pieces:
        if piece.startswith('-'):
            exclude.append(re.compile(piece[1:]))
        else:
            include.append(re.compile(piece))
    def validator(s):
        return (all(r.search(s) for r in include) and
                not any(r.search(s) for r in exclude))
    return validator
```

This will return a function that you can use to validate against the query, for example:

```
>>> test = foo('matchthis -butnothis -"and not this"')
>>> test("we should matchthis...")
True
>>> test("some stuff matchthis blah and not this...")
False
```

You should be able to add in some wildcard handling by replacing `*` in the query with `.*` in the regex.

Answer (score 3):

There's no one standard library module that does all of what you want; however, you can start with the *[shlex module](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html#module-shlex)* to parse the search groups:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> s = '''matchthis -butnothis -"and not this"
this|orthis|"or this"
brand new*laptop
"exact phrase"
'''
>>> shlex.split(s)
['matchthis', '-butnothis', '-and not this', 'this|orthis|or this', 'brand', 'new*laptop', 'exact phrase']
```

You can also look at the *[re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-re)* in case you need more fine grained control over the parsing.

Comment: I've thought about using regex but I'm under the impression that it would be very slow for a list about 1000 long with each text being paragraph or two.

Comment: If you precompile regexes, they can be very fast and hard to beat with any other pure python technique.